# Unable to update shopify product via API using XML

Tags: shopify

I am using shopify API with a private api key for my demo partner store. I am unable to update a product. I get  200 response but nothing has changed. I am using Fiddler for this.

Here is my URL.

```
https://brown-davis8963.myshopify.com/admin/products/110503384.xml
```

with Headers

```
Authorization: Basic <REDACTED>
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Request Body

```
<product>
  <id type="integer">110503384</id>
  <title>Football</title>
</product>
```

Comment: David Underwood don't edit my post! I left the Authorization token there on purpose as this is only a demo store!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your content type needs to be `application/xml`

Comment: That appeared to be my issue. Can't believe I overlooked that. I thought maybe it was the content type, but i also thought it was suppose to be text/xml. Thanks!